# Omit the the .1 from figure numbering when there's only one figure in a chapter

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, labels, books

In the book class, figures are by default numbered as \thechapter.\arabic{figure}. However, the {figure} numbering is redundant when there is only a single figure in a chapter.

In such a case, how do I remove the \arabic{figure} from the figure label, so the single figure is just labelled and referenced as Figure \thechapter instead of Figure \thechapter.\arabic{figure}

In my MWE, I have chapter 1 containing two figures (with default labeling) and chapter 2 containing only one figure. How do I get that figure to only be labeled as Figure 2 instead of Figure 2.1

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter with two figures}

In this chapter, Figures \ref{fig1.1} and \ref{fig1.2} are labeled as intended.

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure is labeled 1.1 as intended}
    \label{fig1.1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Figure is labeled 1.2 as intended}
    \label{fig1.2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second chapter with one single figure}

In this chapter the only Figure \ref{fig2} should be labeled and referenced as just 2, not 2.1.

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-c}
    \caption{This is the only figure in this chapter. The .1 in the numbering is redundant and I would like to remove it.}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The reason why I want to remove the \arabic{figure} from lone figures is because a .1 could be interpreted as an implication for at least a .2.

Note that the numbering I am suggesting keeps all figure labels unique.

Comment: Just a thought. If you redefine figure labelling to a single (figure) number just within a chapter, hence locally, I think you are going to confuse readers, especially if you have more than one this kind of chapters. The global format would still be `chapter.figure` and figure numbers would still get reset per chapters. You end up with a number of figures labelled as `Figure 1: ...`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. In the book class, figures are by default labeled as \thechapter.\arabic{figure}. My question was how to remove the \arabic{figure} part of the label, not the \thechapter (and that only if there is a single figure in a chapter). So all figure labels would indeed still be unique.
I added that description in my original question too.
Cheers

Comment: In that case, you just need to redefine figure numbering to `\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}}` for chapters with a single figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think there are more chapters containing labels only with a single figure, I would suggest to turn off resetting a figure number per chapter. This way labels will remain unique across the document.

One way to achieve the above is to use

```
\counterwithout*{figure}{chapter}
```

a starred version, so that format of `\thefigure` remains the same across the document. Then, redefine the label only sparsely in those figure environments which does not require chapter numbers. I created a new environment called `slfigure` for this purpose which contain the line

```
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
```

Here is the example

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}   % [openany] only for demonstration to avoid empty pages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}  % For \adjustboxset

\counterwithout*{figure}{chapter}    % Prevents from resetting figure numbers 
\adjustboxset{width=0.5\linewidth}   % To avoid repetition with \inlcudegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{...}

% This environment redefines figure labelling, locally
\NewDocumentEnvironment{slfigure}{O{} +b}{
  \begin{figure}[#1]
    \renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
    #2
  \end{figure}
}{}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter with only one figure}
In this chapter the only Figure \ref{fig1} should be referenced as just 1, not 1.1.

\begin{slfigure}[tbh]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{Single figure}
  \label{fig1}
\end{slfigure}


\chapter{Chapter with several figures}
In this chapter, the Figures \ref{fig2.2} and \ref{fig2.3} can be referenced as intended.

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
  \caption{Figure is labeled 2.2 as intended}
  \label{fig2.2}
\end{figure}

A sentence between figures

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-c}
  \caption{Figure is labeled 2.3 as intended}
  \label{fig2.3}
\end{figure}


\chapter{Chapter with only one figure}
The second chapter with a single Figure~\ref{fig:4}

\begin{slfigure}[tbh]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{Single figure no. 4}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{slfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks :-D This does exactly what I wanted.
In fact, I do want the figure counter to reset per chapter (I think it's actually the default behavior.). But it works great without that line too.
Love this community :-D

Comment: You could also redefine numbering to matching a chapter number: `\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}}`, which would prevent from having repeated `Figure 1: ...`.

Answer (score 1):

- Welcome to TeX.SE!
- Your question is not entirely clear: how should be numbered figures which are inserted before `\section{...}`?
- I anticipate, that the same as if no sections in chapter
- In this case try to add in your preamble the following code snippet:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}%
{
\ifnum\arabic{section}=0
    \renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\else
    \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\fi
}
```

- complete MWE (a wee a bit changed your MWE)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}%
{
\ifnum\arabic{section}=0
    \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\else
    \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter with only one figure}

In this chapter the only Figure \ref{fig1} should be referenced as just 1, not 1.1.



\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is the only figure in this chapter. The .1 in the numbering is redundant and I would like to remove it.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is the only figure in this chapter}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}


\chapter{Chapter with several figures}


\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure is labeled 2.1 as intended}
    \label{fig2.1}
\end{figure}

\section{first section in the second chapter}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure is labeled 2.2 as intended}
    \label{fig2.2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

gives

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. By default, the book document class ignores sections and just labels figures as \thechapter.\arabic{figure}. I don't want to change anything about that.
But your code does in fact describe the situation when figures are to be labeled as \thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{figure}, which is also valid.